# In jetpack compose how to add numbers(counts) near icons(like,comment)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, icons, placeholder

[image]
how to add numbers near the icon in android jetapck compose, i have attached snap below like that.please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `BadgedBox`.
Use the `offset` modifier to change the position of the badge, and the `containerColor` to change the background color.
In M2 the background color is defined by the `backgroundColor` attribute.

```
BadgedBox(
    badge = {
        Badge(
            modifier = Modifier.offset(y=10.dp),
            containerColor=LightGray
        ){
            val badgeNumber = "8"
            Text(
                badgeNumber,
                modifier = Modifier.semantics {
                    contentDescription = "$badgeNumber new notifications"
                }
            )
        }
    }) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Star,
        contentDescription = "Favorite"
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: @sakthivel.kt wrap the IconButton in the BadgedBox

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code below:

```
@Composable
fun IconsRow() {
    // Update the texts according to your logic
    var favoriteText by remember { mutableStateOf("34") }
    var repeatText by remember { mutableStateOf("12") }
    var chatText by remember { mutableStateOf("12") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            IconWithNearbyText(
                text = chatText,
                icon = Icons.Outlined.ChatBubbleOutline
            )
            IconWithNearbyText(
                text = repeatText,
                icon = Icons.Outlined.Repeat
            )
            IconWithNearbyText(
                text = favoriteText,
                icon = Icons.Outlined.FavoriteBorder
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun IconWithNearbyText(
    text: String,
    icon: ImageVector
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp)
    ) {
        Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = null)
        Text(text = text)
    }
}
```